# Achieving parallelism using Parallel.ForEach without breaking the order of program

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I'm trying to make my C# application run as fast as possible.

I don't have access to the source code of the application, but it's allowed to extend it using C#, so that's I'm doing. I don't know whether this makes any difference or not.

In addition, this has to run more than ten times a second. Performance is very important to me, so I decided to use `Parallel.ForEach()`.

**How can I define an order (I'm not talking about the original order of the array) so things don't get hairy?**

Here's my code:

```
string[] MyThings = {}; // There are 300 names in this array.

System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(MyThings, Thing => {
  var LastStatus = AppLib.FetchNode(Thing); 
  // First step. AppLib.FetchNode() sends my Node.js server a request,  
  // Node.js accesses MySQL and returns a response.

  // Second step. I access application specific data here using LastStatus value, 
  // but it shouldn't run before the first step is finished.

  var SendStatus = AppLib.SendNode(data1, data2, data3);
  // Third and last step. SendNode() sends some data to my Node.js server, 
  // but it shouldn't run before the second step is finished.
});
```

Comment: If there are ordering requirements, it's probably not parallelizable.

Comment: @PeterRitchie , thanks! What's the term I'm looking for?

Comment: It looks fine. You define the order by ordering lines of code (duh), which is what you did. Processing your 300 Things using the task parallel library will probably speed your program up compared with doing it sequentially. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Verdolino , Regrettably, I didn't, I thought it wouldn't work that way due to MySQL's delay. Trying now.

Comment: This should make some improvement, but there is probably a different way to do it with more improvement.

Comment: Actually, let's think about this. This must happen @ > 10Hz, and you have 300 names. So you need to make 3000 mysql queries per second? Not to mention accessing application data, then uploading to your Node.js server, each 3000 times per second? I'm not sure this will be possible.

Comment: Assuming 1ms to query mysql, 1 ms to access your app data, and 1ms to upload to your server, I can do 300 iterations in about 186ms on my machine. That's about 6 Hz.

Comment: Your problem is "I ordered 300 books from Amazon, and I want them to arrive faster, so I hired 20 clerks to wait for the books to arrive. That will make them arrive 20 times faster, right?"  If the work was "read these 300 books" then hiring 20 people gets the work done 20 times faster. But if the work is "wait for them to arrive", then hiring more people to wait doesn't make stuff arrive faster.

Comment: In other words: parallelism is about increasing performance of processor-bound problems. Asynchronous workflows are about increasing processor utilization in IO-bound problems. Neither makes your network card or your database server work faster, and certainly neither improves the speed at which signals propagate in copper wires.

Comment: Thanks for all replies. I'll run this application on a server with 8 cores, I hope it'll work fast enough. @Eric Lippert , so I'm trying to solve a problem that doesn't occur if you have enough processing power, is that correct?

Comment: @Verdolino , thanks. Do you think it'd possible to achieve this using a server that has 8 cores, 32 gb ram and a fast SSD disk or would I have to split my list into smaller lists and run each on different servers? Different question, how  can I calculate how much power I need?

Comment: Maybe you should rethink your architecture. Do you really need the overhead associated with hitting sql @ 3kHz? Maybe you can query all the names in a single query? Then make a single call to the application data, then a single call to upload to your server. Maybe since you don't have all the source code, a reasonable solution is impossible based on your requirement. Yeah, maybe you could throw 8 servers at this problem, but is it really worth the investment?

Comment: @salep We have insufficient information to know the answer to that question.